# logback-core 1.4.1 with spring-boot 2.6.6 - 2.7.4 failing with ClassNotFoundException:AbstractEventEvaluatorAction

Tags: spring-boot, logback

After updating logback-core from 1.2.7 to 1.4.1 in a quite basic springboot app I got this:

```
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.configureByResourceUrl(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:186)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:66)
    ...
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AbstractEventEvaluatorAction
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
```

there is indeed no AbstractEventEvaluatorAction in the logback anymore but can't find any references to it in the springboot either. Can it somehow creep in from configuration or some external resource?

same error with spring-boot 2.6.6 and 2.7.4

Comment: Spring Boot 2.7.4 dependency management brings in Logback 1.2.11. Spring Boot applications typically use the Spring Boot curated dependency versions. Why do you want to use a different Logback version?

Comment: Chin Huang, frankly no idea, just was in the project I've inherited, but why not - last breaking change was in v1.0.2 https://logback.qos.ch/news.html.

Comment: the update rq to 1.4.1 was actually from dependabot, there were some vulnerabilities, but removing direct depenency seems to be enough to silence it :)

Comment: and I still don't understand where from springboot took that AbstractEventEvaluatorAction...

Comment: @user656449, have you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: nope, had to keep 1.2.7